# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Callable expects 4 arguments, but 3 were provided

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I'm trying to invoke a function using Kotlin reflection, but I'm getting the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Callable expects 4 arguments, but
>   3 were provided.

This is the code doing the reflective call:

```
    annotation.listeners.forEach { listener: KClass<*> ->
        listener.functions.forEach { function: KFunction<*> ->
            if (function.name == "before") {
                function.call(annotation.action, request, response)
            }
        }
    }
```

I've added types for `listener` and `function` just to make the question more readable.

This is the method that's being called:

```
fun before(action: String, request: RestRequest, response: RestResponse)
```

To double check that my types are correct, I did this:

```
if (function.name == "before") {
    println(annotation.action::class)
    println(request::class)
    println(response::class)
}
```

This prints (which is the correct types needed for the `before` function):

> ```
> class kotlin.String
> class com.mycompany.RestRequest
> class com.mycompany.RestResponse
> ```

What should the fourth paramater be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the "this" parameter which is the object that the method should be called with respect to.

it should be the first argument to the method

Comment: ah, yes, it obviously needs an instance to call it on.

Answer (score 4):

It's not obvious directly, but let's have a look at the doc of [`KCallable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/):

```
/**
 * Calls this callable with the specified list of arguments and returns the result.
 * Throws an exception if the number of specified arguments is not equal to the size of [parameters],
 * or if their types do not match the types of the parameters
 */
 public fun call(vararg args: Any?): R
```

"Throws an exception if the number of arguments is not equal to the size of [parameters] [...]". Parameters on the other hand is a `List<KParameter>` with following DOC:

```
 /**
 * Parameters required to make a call to this callable.
 * If this callable requires a `this` instance or an extension receiver parameter,
 * they come first in the list in that order.
 */
public val parameters: List<KParameter>
```

"If this callable requires a `this` instance [...] [it] come[s] first in the list in that order."

Like bennyl already answered correctly, a `this` instance is the first parameter, coming before the other three because the method needs an instance to be called on.

You can see it when you look at `parameter`'s content:

```
class X{

    fun before(action: String, request: String, response: String)= println("called")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    X::class.functions.forEach { function: KFunction<*> ->
        if (function.name == "before") {
            function.parameters.forEach{ println(it)}
            //function.call(X(), "a", "b", "c")
        }
    }
}
```

The printed `parameter` looks as follows:

> instance of fun de.swirtz.jugcdemo.prepared.X.before(kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit
>
> parameter #1 action of fun de.swirtz.jugcdemo.prepared.X.before(kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit
>
> parameter #2 request of fun de.swirtz.jugcdemo.prepared.X.before(kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit
>
> parameter #3 response of fun de.swirtz.jugcdemo.prepared.X.before(kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit

Comment: I saw that when I did an inspection on the `call` method, hence the reason I printed the types in my question to confirm that my types are correct. Where did you find the second comment block? Would be nice if the first comment block mentioned that the first param should be the instance, although it's probably obvious if you've done it before.

Comment: It's both in `KCallable`:)

Comment: Ah, right, `Calls this callable with the specified`, that `this` actually refers to the instance, I understood that sentence somewhat different when I read it in the source code and in your copy paste of the comment block. The second comment block would have been obvious immediately.